# Trying to output user's name in a chatbox... how do I do this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, button, placeholder

How can I make my code display the user's inputted name instead of 'User: ' in my chatbox simulation? The bot will prompt the user for their name, and after they input it, the code should take the name and start using it every time a question is asked.

This is my current code (again, not all):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ask-button").click(function() {
    if ($("#ask-button").val() == 'Start') {
      var name = $('#txtType').val();
      var message = '<p><b> Bot: </b> Hello ' + name + '!</p>'
      $('#chatbox').append(message);
      $('#txtType').attr('placeholder', 'Type your message...');
      //$("#ask-button span").text("Ask");
      $("#ask-button").html('Start');
    }
else if ($("#ask-button").text()=='Ask'){
 var questionText=$("#txtType").val();

 if (questionText == '')
 {
  return false;
 }
 var chatBoxText=$("#chatbox").val();
 var html =  name + ": " + questionText;
 
 $("#chatbox").append(html);
 
 var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
 objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
<div id="chatbox">
  <p><b>Bot: </b> Welcome! I am your incident management chatbot (IMC). Let me know if you have any questions. What is your name?</p>
</div>
<br/>
<textarea id="txtType" placeholder="Enter your name..." name="message" required></textarea>

<!-- INSERT CODE HERE -->

<!-- **IMPORTANT** this is what should be integrated w/QnA Maker -->
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="ask-button">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The button doesn't have a value so the `if ($("#ask-button").val() == 'Start')` condition doesn't work. Even if it did, it's pointless. Once you've remove that your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n4eLhyg3/. What's the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem is that I only want to ask for their name once. After that, I need to use their name instead of the word 'User'. After they input their name, they can begin asking questions. Said questions have answers which I call from an API.

Comment: You've got their name in the `name` variable, though.

Comment: `$("#ask-button").val()` should be `$("#ask-button").text()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` to get the contents of the button, not `.val()`. And you didn't change it to `Ask`, you set it back to `Start` again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ask-button").click(function() {
    if ($("#ask-button").text() == 'Start') {
      var name = $('#txtType').val();
      var message = '<p><b> Bot: </b> Hello ' + name + '!</p>'
      $('#chatbox').append(message);
      $('#txtType').attr('placeholder', 'Type your message...');
      //$("#ask-button span").text("Ask");
      $("#ask-button").html('Ask');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
<div id="chatbox">
  <p><b>Bot: </b> Welcome! I am your incident management chatbot (IMC). Let me know if you have any questions. What is your name?</p>
</div>
<br/>
<textarea id="txtType" placeholder="Enter your name..." name="message" required></textarea>

<!-- INSERT CODE HERE -->

<!-- **IMPORTANT** this is what should be integrated w/QnA Maker -->
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="ask-button">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Now how can I make the chatbox display the user's name instead of 'User: ' every time the user asks a question?

Comment: I don't see that in the code. But you can do it similarly to the way you do the `message` variable.